# Python Pandas How to choose range of 10 values from the middle index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, plotly

Here i am trying to plot interactive chart using plotly for this the input is pandas dataframe.

Since the data frame has huge data sets the chart looks very lean and not in readable format.I want to plot only 10 left and 10 right from the middle.

My requirement is to select mid of pandas data frame and choose 10 index above and below for plotting.
How this operation can be achieved using python pandas.
Sample code is below . here x is shared between three trace and data series are  y=df['OI'],y=df['pOI'],y=df['cchangeoi'],

X axist is date ,y is data within some range.

```
def groupstacked_bar_chart_exp(df,SCRIPTCODE):
    trace1 = go.Bar(
        #x=stock_opt_pe.index
        base =0,
        width=0.4,
        offset=0.0,
        x=df['Sprice'],
        y=df['OI'],
        name='OI',
        orientation = 'v',
        marker = dict(
            color = 'rgba(102,51,255,1)',
            #line = dict(
                #color = 'rgba(246, 246, 246, 1.0)',
                #color = 'rgb(60, 60, 60)',
                #width = 0)
        )
    )
    trace2 = go.Bar(
        #x=stock_opt_pe.index
        width=0.4,
        offset=-0.4,
        x=df['SPrice'],
        y=df['pOI'],
        name='pOI',
        orientation = 'v',
        marker = dict(
            color = 'rgba(102,0,153,1)',
            #line = dict(
                #color = 'rgba(246, 246, 246, 1.0)',
                #color = 'rgb(60, 60, 60)',
                #width = 0)
        )
    )

    trace3 = go.Bar(
        #x=stock_opt_pe.index
        width=0.4,
        offset=-0.4,
        x=df['SPrice'],
        y=df['cchangeoi'],
        name='cchangeoi',
        orientation = 'v',
        marker = dict(
            color = 'rgba(255,255,0,1)',
            #line = dict(
                #color = 'rgba(246, 246, 246, 1.0)',
                #color = 'rgb(60, 60, 60)',
                #width = 0)
        )
    )

    odata = [trace1,trace2,trace3]
```

Comment: Do you want something like `df.iloc[mid-10:mid+10]`?

Comment: @QuangHoang In my case what shall be the change to adapt the above logic. y=df['OI']